# How to pass map indexes to array items compose of jsx element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I had this code where I could not pass the key index of the array item map.

```
arrayItem = [function1, function2, function3]

<div>
   {arrayItem.map((item, index) => (<Box key={index}>{item}</Box>}
</div>
```

ex. for function1

```
const function1 = (index) => { <div> <h1> test</h1> <Button onClick((index) => console.log(index,"array number")}
```

It seems that I could not retrieve the index from the map when it goes to function1. The index according the console in the map is numeric but when it goes to the function, it is a `className {}`. The purpose of this is to retrieve the number of the array so that I could put the button delete and delete the specific array according to the index. Btw, the arrayItems is not static, so it can have more than one functions.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I tried this one => {arrayItem.map((item, index) => (<Box key={index}>{item(index)}</Box>))} it had an error, it says "Invariant Violation: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React keys are special and not treated as any part of `props`, similarly as-is with React refs`. These are not exposed to the children components. If you need to pass an` index` value to a child it needs to be passed as a prop.

```
arrayItem = [item1, item2, item3]

<div>
  {arrayItem.map((item, index) => (
    <Box
      key={index}
      index={index} // <-- pass as a valid prop
    >
      {item}
    </Box>
  )}
</div>
```

Seems you are wanting to receive the `index` as a prop, then it needs to be accessed from `props`.

```
const function1 = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <Button onClick(() => console.log(prop.index, "array number")
  ...
)
```

Now it seems that you have an array of functional components and you want to pass the index to ***that*** component. In this case you need to render it as JSX and not just as a passed function.

```
<div>
  {arrayItem.map((Component, index) => ( // <-- give proper PascalCased component name
    <Component
      key={index}
      index={index} // <-- pass as a valid prop
    />
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Drew if you want to treat them as `component` you need to use `<item index={index} />`

Comment: @TaghiKhavari `item` isn't a valid React component.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider your items as just normal functions you can pass `index` as parameter to these function and then call them like this

```
<div>
   {arrayItem.map((item, index) => (<Box key={index}>{item(index)}</Box>))}
</div>
```

also you have some mistakes in your functions, you need to `return` some `jsx` from it. and you have a typo in`onClick((...`. try this:

```
const function1 = (index) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> test</h1>
      <Button onClick={(index) => console.log(index, "array number")}>click me</Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

There is another senario that you consider your `arrayItem` an array of `React Function Component`. in that case you need change your code to this and pass `index` as a prop:

```
<div>
   {arrayItem.map((FunctionComponent, index) => (<Box key={index}><FunctionComponent index={index} /></Box>))}
</div>
```

and then use the `index` like this:

```
const function1 = ({index}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> test</h1>
      <Button onClick={(index) => console.log(index, "array number")}>click me</Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: It does not work, it had an error, it says rendered too many hooks. The arrayItem adding is a select textfield where everytime I will select any selections, it will just stockpile the array with jsx functions.

Comment: Thanks, I had the other scenario. it works.